# Couldn't find executable named drone_stateestimation

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to fly the ardrone parrot 2.0 using tum_ardrone ptam module. It is a rospackage, so I had to make it using

```
       rosmake tum_ardrone
```

The above compiled with 0 failures. however, when I do the following commad

```
       rosrun tum_ardrone drone_stateestimation
```

I get the following error

```
      [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named drone_stateestimation below

      /home/bojan/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone
```

I tried to google and get a solid pipelined solution to check for the reason for this error and solve it, but I did not get it. Am new to ubuntu, thus your help is much appreicated. This error doesn't seem to be package specific since the same package works fine in another laptop I tested. Am runnign Ubuntu in vmWare. Does that make any difference?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE :

This is the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as you asked.

/home/bojan/fuerte_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

The first path is the path I get after roscd. Please let me know if this information helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141431/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-drone_stateestimation/) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-18**:
Please post the output of echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH because it sounds like you didn't source your setup.bash on the non-working machine.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-18**:
ROS in a virtual machine doesn't inevitably lead to problems, but it could when it comes to OpenGL and USB-devices. We always recommend our students to install Ubuntu natively. Nevertheless your current problems does not correspond to a virtual machine issue.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2014-03-19**:
@BennyRe Please check the edit.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-20**:
Hm PATH looks good. Try re-sourcing your setup.bash after running rosmake.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-21**:
Opening a new question with more information about this problem isn't a good practice. You would have made this a lot easier if you would have wrote that this executable actually doesn't exist and not only ROS can't find it.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2014-03-21**:
Benny, am really sorry. I just came to know about the new issue, after exploring for a while. And am new to ubuntu and still learning. So please bare with me if I do post such questions that are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the same problem and here is how i solved it. 1) remove the tum_ardrone in your workspace 2)go to https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone 3) and select the branch as "fuerte-devel" because you are using ROS-Fuerte 4) download the tum_ardrone zip folder 5) unzip the folder in your workspace 7) change the name of your folder to tum_ardrone 8) execute command "rosmake tum_ardrone" 9) "cd tum_ardrone" and you see a "bin" folder which means you are ready to execute " rosrun tum_ardrone drone_stateestimation".

---

Originally posted by [mar_max](https://answers.ros.org/users/17901/mar_max/) with karma: 16 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0